# Thirty thousand troops without cover?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

A small side-note in [the Waltz episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Waltz_(episode)) of Deep Space Nine made me really curious.

How it is possible that the Federation, losing the war against Dominion at that particular moment in time, deployed a convoy of thirty thousand soldiers on a transportation ship that was not covered at all by a warship? (The Defiant was the only one sent to secure that convoy, and only reached it after a long time.)

Such a decision seems very strange in any time, even today.

Is there any explanation that I missed? For me, sending thirty thousand troops without cover sounds like giving the enemy a kind of cannon fodder-like surprise.

Comment: As you say, they’re losing a war. They have to work with what they’ve got. The Defiant may have been the closest warship.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Sounds like a good answer. Why only a comment then?

Comment: I figured someone would pop in with an answer with references. [And lo!](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139480/440)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Federation is desperately short of ships by this point in the conflict.

> **KIRA:** *With all the Dominion activity along the border, that's all Starfleet can spare at the moment.*

In order to free up a ship, they send the convoy through the Badlands, where an escort ship is basically unnecessary.

> **KIRA:** *But this convoy  is completely unprotected.  **They've been using the
> plasma fields in the Badlands to hide their movements,***
>
> ...
>
> *In fifty-two hours you have to be  at this rendezvous point outside
> the Badlands. You're the escort for a Federation troop convoy.*
>
> ...
>
> *but when they  emerge they'll be **helpless without the Defiant.***